# A sequence contains two numbers congruent modulo $(10^{\beta}-1)m$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\beta \geq 1$ be an integer and $m$ be an integer relatively prime to $10$. Prove that the sequence $1,10^{\beta},10^{2\beta},\ldots$ contains two numbers congruent modulo $(10^{\beta}-1)m$ and as a result for some $k>0$, $10^{k\beta} \equiv 1 \pmod{(10^{\beta}-1)m}$ using Fermat's theorem.

First suppose that the two numbers in the sequence congruent modulo $(10^{\beta}-1)m$ are both positive powers of $10$. Then, $10^{m\beta} \equiv 10^{p\beta} \pmod{(10^{\beta}-1)m}$. What do I do from here?

**Context:**

[image]

Comment: The conclusion is not true unless you have some assumption on $m$. For example if $m=10$, then no power of $10$ can ever be congruent to $1$ modulo any multiple of $m$.

Comment: On the other hand, if you can assume that $m$ is coprime to $10$, then the smaller power of $10^\beta$ has an inverse modulo $(10^\beta-1)m$; multiply both powers by that inverse.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right. I left out the part about $m$ being relatively prime to $10$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm How is it a consequence of Fermat's theorem?

Comment: Observe that if you pick more than $(10^{\beta}-1)m$ numbers, then two of them must be congruent.

Comment: Hmm, the instruction to use "Fermat's theorem" (by which I assume Fermat's _little_ theorem is meant) is strange. That theorem doesn't seem to apply here; it requires a prime modulus. You can reach the conclusion by using _Euler's_ theorem which generalizes Fermat's, but then you don't need the initial pigeonhole argument at all -- just observe that $10^\beta$ is coprime to $(10^\beta-1)m$, and therefore $(10^\beta)^{\varphi((10^\beta-1)m)}\equiv 1 \pmod{(10^\beta-1)m}$, case closed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I posted the picture in the question. The question I asked came from a similar question to this one and they derived this result.